# Inequalities as python parameters

Tags: python, class, linear-programming

Firstly, Sry fo the bad title of this question I simply don't know a better one.
If you have a better one => Tell me!

So my problem is that I would like to write a simplex solver in Python by myself to deeply understand how they work.

Therefore, I would like to have something like this in my program:

```
 m.addConstr(x[0] <= 7)
```

Which basically should add a constraint to my model `m`.
This works in Gurobi which is just wonderful cause it's so easy to read.
The problem is that `x[0]` has to be an object where I itself can define what should happen when there is an inequality or equality or whatever, right?

I am happy to figure out most of the stuff by myself would just like to get an idea how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to overload the comparison operators of whatever objects you're working with. So if `Foo` is the class of `x[0]` in your example, then you could write it like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __gt__(self, other):
        # construct and return some kind of constraint object

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # likewise
```

These special methods (`__gt__`, `__ge__`, `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__ne__` and `__eq__`) are called for the left-hand object in a comparison relation. So if you have `x > y`, then the `__gt__` method on `x` is called with `y` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it should be your first concern to come up with an elegant input syntax. You should rather implement the simplex algorithm first.

I suggest, you handle the input by writing a parser for the two standard formats for linear programming problems: [`.lp`](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/lp-format.htm) and [`.mps`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPS_(format))

If you still want to know how to implement proper expression handling in Python I recommend you have a look at [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt) since this is exactly doing what you want and you can inspect the entire source code.

Comment: I'm thinking about doing most of the stuff inline in Python as it is done in Gurobi normally​. Then you have a lot of freedom. I'll have a look at the .lp syntax. Thanks for the links!